# get onChange/onBlur effect of editable select

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

i used the library on this page https://indrimuska.github.io/jquery-editable-select/ to make an editable select and it worked perfectly . The challenge is now getting the onChange/onBlur effect when i manually key in an option .

```
$('#select')
.editableSelect()
.on('select.editable-select', function (e, li) {
    $('#last-selected').html(
        li.val() + '. ' + li.text()
    );
});
```

the above work greatly if i select an option that is already in the select but didnt work if i manually enter an option.

i have already tried

```
$('#select').on('change', function() {
alert( this.value );
```

});

and `

$("#select").blur(function () {

```
alert("Handler for .blur() called.");
```

});

with no luck`

Comment: You can use focusout instead of blur.

Comment: focusout didnt solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I got it .

```
$('#select')
    .editableSelect()
    .on('blur', function (e, li) {
       alert("the select is blurred");
    });
```

worked perfectly